# Windows Server 2012 R2 port 443 open, stopping IIS doesn't work

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, https, port

Sorry for the bad wording in the title, 'doesn't help' is not allowed as a title, I am definitely able to stop IIS.

While trying to install VisualSVN I ran into the problem that port 443 was already open. After looking through dozens of forum entries and checking netstat [(screengrab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfzk.jpg) I was only able to find out that PID 4 caused the issue, and Process Explorer confirmed the port being listened in the properties window [(screengrab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq8De.jpg).

Now in all those posts Process Explorer was referred to for finding out which service is the culprit, but I cannot really figure out which service in particular opened the port, all I can really see is the listing under TCP/IP. Now I *do* have IIS installed and plan on setting up websites in the future, for now there is only the default site installed. When I stop the website the listing for port :http and :80 disappear from netstat and Process Explorer, 433 is still there though. Same goes for stopping the entire IIS server in the Manager window or just stopping the IIS service(s).

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have routing and remote access service installed? If yes, try to disable it (RRAS uses SSTP by default and it listens for 443 port and lsas.exe process which is using port in your situation is used for IPSEC also).

Comment: Yes! Finally, that's it, now how can I change the RRAS port from 443 to something else?

Comment: Also, do you by any chance have an idea how I can fix the VPN Status page just showing Unavailable at every entry?

Comment: If you don't want to remove RRAS role (in case you really need it), disable SSTP port. Go to Routing and Remote access management, choose ports and change available port quantity for SSTP protocol from 128 (default) to 0

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 about VPN Status page: I didn't get you full, can you send link to screenshot please?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh1y6.jpg I dont even have remote access enabled, I just really need the VPN, and it only comes with the remote access.

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 that's a different control. That one called Remote Access Management Console but what you need called Routing and Remote access (placed also in tools). Unfortunately I don't have now test server with VPN installed to show, so here is step by step guide https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458965.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (remember, you need set SSTP port to 0).

Comment: Ah yes, it was the wrong config window, that's why I didnt find the port properties. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39145/discussion-between-senator14-and-no-one-910).

Comment: I cannot set the number to 0. Also I've joined the chat now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to run into major issues running both IIS and VisualSVN, which installs and runs on Apache, on the exact same server.  If I were you, I'd separate them out and give each web server their own VM.  I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I'm wondering if your original posted problem is not a symptom of trying to run both web servers on the same VM.

Comment: well, what problems would that be? All seems to work fine now.

Comment: Well I based my original response on the fact that your issue is not a typical experience when installing VisualSVN.  The fact that you've had to do some workarounds or troubleshooting means you have conflicts that are not standard.  It isn't a stretch to think you won't see other issues down the road as well.  

Personally, I've just never been a fan of monolithic servers like that which run multiple services.  I have all my IIS VMs separate from all my Apache VMs.  Also, I would be very concerned about Apache vulnerabilities now exposing threats to your sites that run on IIS and vice versa.